# Kotlin Multiplatform: MOKO : Binding Complex types in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, kotlin-multiplatform

So I am working on KMP app which uses the MOKO framework (https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-mvvm)

I have created my ViewModel etc which contains an Object(Thermostat)

```
data class Thermostat(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val zoneName: String,
)
```

I then define it in my model as a CMutableStateFlow

```
 val thermostatFlow: CMutableStateFlow<Thermostat> = MutableStateFlow(thermostat).cMutableStateFlow()
```

I now want to bind this to a SwiftUi TextField

```
TextField(viewState.thermostat.name, text: viewState.binding(\.thermostat.name))
```

**Key path value type 'String' cannot be converted to contextual type
'CMutableStateFlow'**

It works for Strings and Ints however not for my own type of objects.  What am I missing here?  Do I need to write my own binding function?

Comment: Hi. did you find solution for this case?